# Subscripts in the titles of questions?

Tags: discussion

How did they get subscripts in the title of [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19763/why-is-pbcl%E2%82%84-covalent) question? It's like Latex in the title without Latex in the title! It would greatly beautify our titles if we could do this for all questions, especially if it doesn't interfere with search results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are Unicode subscripts and superscripts you can use. Take a look at [this answer from ManishEarth](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/185/1499) mentioning it as an alternative for LaTeX in titles. Unfortunately it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  We were encouraging this for a while when the site first started, but the unicode characters don't fare much better in the URL slugs.

Answer (score 6):

While Unicode sub- and superscripts are certainly a way to include it in the question titles, it has a couple of flaws, as pointed out by Nicolau, jonsca and Manish. The only advantages I can see is, that they reduce the occurrences of `ce` in the url and the display of the title in the search engines.

I personally prefer using trivial/ common names wherever possible, i.e. substitute $\ce{H2O}$ with water. For the given example, lead (IV) chloride would probably lead to better results in searches.

Most of the titles can be written in plain text, without formatting, it just needs a little bit more effort. But anyhow, these titles are still better than any of the questions with [buzzwords](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583/4945).

Comment: We all love buzzwords, don't we?